# Find a path in a complete graph with cost limit and max reward

Tags: algorithm, graph

I'm looking for an algorithm to solve this problem. I have to implement it (so I need a not np solution XD)

I have a **complete graph** with a **cost** on each arch and a **reward** on each vertex. I have only a start point, but it doesn't matter the end point, becouse the problem is to find a path to see as many vertex as possible, in order to have the maximum reward possible, but subject to a maximum cost limit.  (for this reason it doesn't matter the end position).

I think to find the optimum solution is a np-hard problem, but also an approximate solution is apprecciated :D

Thanks

I'm trying study how to solve the problem with branch & bound...

**update: complete problem dscription**

I have a region in which there are several areas identify by its id and x,y,z position. Each vertex identifies one ot these areas. The maximum number of ares is 200. 
From a start point **S**, I know the cost, specified in **seconds** and inserted in the arch (so only integer values), to reach each vertex from each other vertex (a complete graph).
When I visit a vertex I get a reward (float valiues).

My objective is to find a paths in a the graph that **maximize the reward** but I'm subject to a **cost constraint** on the paths. Indeed I have only limited minutes to complete the path (for example 600 seconds.)

The graph is made as matrix adjacency matrix for the cost and reward (but if is useful I can change the representation).

I can visit vertex more time but with one reward only!

Comment: How many vertices do you have and how large is the cost limit? There is a straightforward pseudopolynomial O(n^2 * C) algorithm where C is the cost limit and n is the number of vertices.

Comment: This is not a well stated problem. You are either looking for a path with the maximum possible reward, or with as many vertices as possible, it can't be both at the same time.

Comment: Are the arc costs a metric? Can you revisit vertices? If you can revisit vertices, do you get the reward multiple times?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're interested in branch and bound, let's formulate a linear program. Use Floyd–Warshall to adjust the costs minimally downward so that `cost(uw) ≤ cost(uv) + cost(vw)` for all vertices `u, v, w`.

Let `s` be the starting vertex. We have 0-1 variables `x(v)` that indicate whether vertex `v` is part of the path and 0-1 variables `y(uv)` that indicate whether the arc `uv` is part of the path. We seek to maximize

```
sum over all vertices v of reward(v) x(v).
```

The constraints unfortunately are rather complicated. We first relate the `x` and `y` variables.

```
for all vertices v ≠ s,  x(v) - sum over all vertices u of y(uv) = 0
```

Then we bound the cost.

```
sum over all arcs uv of cost(uv) y(uv) ≤ budget
```

We have (pre)flow constraints to ensure that the arcs chosen look like a path possibly accompanied by cycles (we'll handle the cycles shortly).

```
for all vertices v,  sum over all vertices u of y(uv)
                       - sum over all vertices w of y(vw)
                         ≥ -1 if v = s
                            0 if v ≠ s
```

To handle the cycles, we add cut covering constraints.

```
for all subsets of vertices T such that s is not in T,
  for all vertices t in T,
    x(t) - sum over all vertices u not in T and v in T of y(uv) ≥ 0
```

Because of the preflow constraints, a cycle necessarily is disconnected from the path structure.

There are exponentially many cut covering constraints, so when solving the LP, we have to generate them on demand. This means finding the minimum cut between `s` and each other vertex `t`, then verifying that the capacity of the cut is no greater than `x(t)`. If we find a violation, then we add the constraint and use the dual simplex method to find the new optimum (repeat as necessary).

I'm going to pass on describing the branching machinery – this should be taken care of by your LP solver anyway.

Comment: Very smart answer. You made me learn some things ... Could you add a little complexity analysis ? I am not able to do it myself since I'm not familiar with the concepts you use. That would get this already great answer even greater :)

Comment: @Rerito It's probably worst-case exponential, but there's a reason that people who study operations research verify performance with experiments rather than theory: the worst-case bounds have little bearing on reality.

Answer (score 0):

### Finding the optimal solution

Here is a recursive approach to solving your problem.

Let's begin with some definitions :

- Let A = (A<sub>i</sub>)<sub>1 ≤ i ≤ N</sub> be the areas.
- Let w<sub>i,j</sub> = w<sub>j,i</sub> the time  cost for traveling from A<sub>i</sub> to A<sub>j</sub> and vice versa.
- Let r<sub>i</sub> the reward for visiting area A<sub>i</sub>

Here is the recursive procedure that will output the exact requested solution : (pseudo-code)

```cpp
List<Area> GetBestPath(int time_limit, Area S, int *rwd) {
    int best_reward(0), possible_reward(0), best_fit(0);
    List<Area> possible_path[N] = {[]};
    if (time_limit < 0) {
        return [];
    }
    if (!S.visited) {
        *rwd += S.reward;
        S.visit();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        if (S.index != i) {
            possible_path[i] = GetBestPath(time_limit - W[S.index][i], A[i], &possible_reward);
            if (possible_reward > best_reward) {
                best_reward = possible_reward;
                best_fit = i;
            }
        }
    }
    *rwd+= best_reward;
    possible_path[best_fit].push_front(S);
    return possible_path[best_fit];
}
```

For obvious clarity reasons, I supposed the A<sub>i</sub> to be globally reachable, as well as the w<sub>i,j</sub>.

### Explanations

You start at **S**. First thing you do ? Collect the reward and mark the node as visited. Then you have to check which way to go is best between the **S**'s N-1 neighbors (lets call them N<sub>S,i</sub> for 1 ≤ i ≤ N-1).

This is the exact same thing as solving the problem for N<sub>S,i</sub> with a time limit of :

> time_limit - W(S ↔ N<sub>S,i</sub>)

And since you mark the visited nodes, when arriving at an area, you first check if it is marked. If so you have no reward ... Else you collect and mark it as visited ...

And so forth !

The ending condition is when time_limit (C) becomes negative. This tells us we reached the limit and cannot proceed to further moves : the recursion ends. The final path may contain useless journeys if all the rewards have been collected before the time limit C is reached. You'll have to "prune" the output list.

### Complexity ?

Oh this solution is soooooooo awful in terms of complexity !
Each calls leads to N-1 calls ... Until the time limit is reached. The longest possible call sequence is yielded by going back and forth each time on the shortest edge. Let w<sub>min</sub> be the weight of this edge.

Then obviously, the overall complexity is bounded by N<sup>C/w<sub>min</sub></sup>.C/w<sub>min</sub>.
This is huuuuuge.

---

### Another approach

Maintain a hash table of all the visited nodes.
On the other side, maintain a **Max-priority queue** (eg. using a *MaxHeap*) of the nodes that have not been collected yet. (The top of the heap is the node with the highest reward). The priority value for each node A<sub>i</sub> in the queue is set as the couple (r<sub>i</sub>, E[w<sub>i,j]</sub>)

1. Pop the heap : `Target <- heap.pop()`.
2. Compute the shortest path to this node using Dijkstra algorithm.
3. Check out the path : If the cost of the path is too high, then the node is not reachable, add it to the unreachable nodes list.

   1. Else collect all the uncollected nodes that you find in it and ...
   2. Remove each collected node from the heap.
   3. Set Target as the new starting point.
4. In either case, proceed to step 1. until the heap is empty.

*Note : A hash table is the best suited to keep track of the collected node. This way, we can check a node in a path computed using Dijkstra in O(1).*

Likewise, maintaining a hashtable leading to the position of each node in the heap might be useful to optimise the "pruning" of the heap, when collecting the nodes along a path.

### A little analysis

This approach is slightly better than the first one in terms of complexity, but may not lead to the optimal result. In fact, it can even perform quite poorly on some graph configurations. For example, if all nodes have a reward r, except one node T that has r+1 and W(N ↔ T) = C for every node N, but the other edges would be all reachable, then this will only make you collect T and miss every other node. In this particular case, the best solution would have been to ignore T and collect everyone else leading to a reward of (N-1).r instead of only r+1.

Comment: yes... this solution is inapplicable. For this reason I'm looking for an approximate solution... like branch & bound or I don't know!!

Comment: @gepeppe I have another idea in mind that may not lead to the best solution but can give interesting results if I'm not mistaken. I need some time to put that down :)

Comment: @gepeppe Here you go ;)